# (Keras) Does the TensorBoard callback work for a recurrent network with return_state on?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I defined a recurrent network with `return_state` set to True:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python import keras

data, targets = np.ones((4, 2, 3)), np.zeros((4, 2, 3))

input_shape = data.shape

input_1 = keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=(None,)+input_shape[1:])

recurrent_1, _, state = keras.layers.LSTM(units=input_shape[-1],
                                          input_shape=input_shape[1:],
                                          return_sequences=True,
                                          return_state=True)(input_1)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_1], outputs=[recurrent_1])
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='RMSprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='/', histogram_freq=1, write_graph=True,
                                                   write_grads=True, write_images=False)

model.fit(data, targets, validation_split=0.25, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

The `fit()` call failed with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joshuaf/PycharmProjects/skyline/catkin_ws/src/learning/src/functional_recurrent_tensorboard.py", line 23, in <module>
    model.fit(data, targets, validation_split=0.25, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
  File "/home/joshuaf/PycharmProjects/skyline/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1348, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/home/joshuaf/PycharmProjects/skyline/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 157, in fit_loop
    callbacks.set_model(callback_model)
  File "/home/joshuaf/PycharmProjects/skyline/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 70, in set_model
    callback.set_model(model)
  File "/home/joshuaf/PycharmProjects/skyline/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 762, in set_model
    tf_summary.histogram('{}_out'.format(layer.name), layer.output)
  File "/home/joshuaf/PycharmProjects/skyline/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/summary.py", line 187, in histogram
    tag=tag, values=values, name=scope)
  File "/home/joshuaf/PycharmProjects/skyline/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_logging_ops.py", line 283, in histogram_summary
    "HistogramSummary", tag=tag, values=values, name=name)
  File "/home/joshuaf/PycharmProjects/skyline/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 528, in _apply_op_helper
    (input_name, err))
ValueError: Tried to convert 'values' to a tensor and failed. Error: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 3 and 2
    From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'lstm_out/packed' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [?,2,3], [?,3], [?,3].
```

I assume the extra two shapes are the hidden state output and cell state, as explained here https://machinelearningmastery.com/return-sequences-and-return-states-for-lstms-in-keras/.

Does that mean the TensorBoard callback simply does not work with layers that return their state? I'm using Tensorflow 1.9 and Keras 2.1.6.